# What's the different between `double(double)` and `double (*)(double)`

Tags: c, function-pointers, cython

The following code works, I think there is no different between `double(double)` and `double (*)(double)`, `square` and `&square`, am I right?

```
#include <stdio.h>

double square(double x)
{
    return x*x;
}

void test1(double f(double), double x)
{
    printf("test1 %f\n", f(x));
}

void test2(double (*f)(double), double x)
{
    printf("test2 %f\n", f(x));
}

int main()
{
    double (*fp)(double);
    test1(square, 3);
    test2(square, 3);
    fp = square;
    test1(fp, 3);
    test2(fp, 3);
    fp = &square;
    test1(fp, 3);
    test2(fp, 3);
    return 0;
}
```

but the following cython code raise **Cannot assign type 'double (*)(double)' to 'double (double)'**, is it a bug or I miss something?

```
from libc.stdio cimport printf

cdef double square(double x):
    return x*x

cdef void test1(double f(double), double x):
    printf("test1=%g\n", f(x))

cdef void test2(double (*f)(double), double x):
    printf("test2=%g\n", f(x))

def test():
    cdef double(*fp)(double)
    fp = square
    test1(fp, 3.0)
    test2(fp, 3.0)
```

Comment: looks like a cython bug

Comment: To answer the question in your first paragraph: yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use that notation in *function parameter list* specifically, there's no difference.

But outside of function parameter context, `double(double)` is *function* type and `double (*)(double)` is *function pointer* type. These are two different types with very different properties.

So, the answer to your first paragraph is: *it is true in function parameter list and only in function parameter list*.

In other words, when used in *function parameter list* function type behaves in a very similar way to array type: it immediately *decays* to pointer type. However, just as array and pointer types are very different, function types and function pointer types are also very different.

In other contexts, if you declare something with type `double(double)`, you declare it as a function. For example

```
typedef double D(double);

D foo;
double foo(double);
```

The above two declarations are valid and equivalent. They declare function `foo` that accepts a single parameter of type `double` and returns `double`. This feature (declaring functions through `typedef` names) is not usually used in actual C code, but nevertheless it is there in the language.

Comment: I use this feature when declaring functions that will be called via a table of function pointers

Answer (score 3):

`double(double)` is the type of a function taking a double and returning a double.

`double(*)(double)` is a pointer to the above function type.

As it happens, functions decay to pointers-to-functions if you breathe on them hard.  For example, you cannot take a function as an argument to another function.  If you try to, the type "decays" into a function pointer.  Similarly, if you pass a function by-name as a parameter (or generally in an expression), it can auto-decay into a function pointer if the target type isn't a reference-to-function or other similar type.

Similar things happen with arrays.

You can also call operator `()` on pointers-to-function, and it automatically dereferences the pointer.

These are legacy features inherited from C.

In C++, you can form references to functions, and you can sometimes make use of pure function types.  `std::function< void(int) >` takes a pure function type.  Now, it cannot create a variable of type `void(int)`, but it can still manipulate the type.

cython maybe doesn't have that auto-conversion decay implemented.

Comment: Function designators virtually always decay (`&` and `sizeof` are the only exceptions and for `sizeof` an operand of function type is invalid), so even in something like `puts("Hello");` the designator `puts` decays to a pointer before the function call operator is applied. You can write `(*puts)("Hello")` or even `(***puts)("Hello")` and so on. (This isn't meant to criticize this post, just a hint for people interested in how the standard models things.)

Answer (score 0):

`double(double)` is semantically exactly equivalent to `double (*)(double)` in parameters: functions and arrays are pass-by-reference. As a local variable however, variables of type `double(double)` can never be lvalues. On a global level they are, of course, functions.

`&square` is the same as `square`, the latter is just syntactic sugar for the first.

I have no experience with cython, but as far as C semantics go, it doesn't seem compliant.

Comment: Strictly speaking, there's no such thing as "variables of type `double(double)`". Declaring anything with such type makes it a function (with the exception of function parameter list context).